# How to classify images using Apache Mahout?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, classification, mahout

How to perform image classification from mahout? How to convert the image to a form which is accepted by mahout classification algorithms? Is the any starter code to start with? Please share me some starter tutorials. Is mahout good library for image classification?

Comment: It's totally depends on what is your task, what actually you want to do with images.

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers to your question:

The simple answer is that from a Mahout point of view classifying images is no different than classifying any other type of data. You find a suitable set of features to describe your data, and then: train, validate, test, and deploy.

The second answer is a bit more involved, and I'm going to summarize. In the case of images the step in which you compute a suitable set of features spans a whole research area (called computer vision). There are many methods: DHOG, direction of gradient, SURF, SIFT, etc. Depending on the images and what your expectations are, you may obtain reasonable results just using an existing method, or maybe not. It would be impossible to say without looking at your images and you telling us your objectives.